# Unable to send data in chunks to server in Golang

Tags: go, multipart

I'm completely new to Golang. I am trying to send a file from the client to the server. The client should split it into smaller chunks and send it to the rest end point exposed by the server. The server should combine those chunks and save it.

This is the [client](https://play.golang.org/p/5P2VTJR9AA) and [server](https://play.golang.org/p/qZEuZuhcqE) code I have written so far. When I run this to copy a file of size 39 bytes, the client is sending two requests to the server. But the server is displaying the following errors.

```
2017/05/30 20:19:28 Was not able to access the uploaded file: unexpected EOF
2017/05/30 20:19:28 Was not able to access the uploaded file: multipart: NextPart: EOF
```

Comment: I don't think form data is the correct content type for arbitrary binary data. I believe it should be application/octet-stream. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962592/whats-content-type-value-within-a-http-request-when-uploading-content

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing buffer with the file into separate chunks and sending each of them as separate HTTP message. This is not how `multipart` is intended to be used.

`multipart` MIME means that a *single* HTTP message may contain one or more entities, quoting [HTTP RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.7.2):

> MIME provides for a number of "multipart" types -- encapsulations of
>   one or more entities within a single message-body. All multipart types
>   share a common syntax, as defined in section 5.1.1 of RFC 2046

You should send the whole file and send it in a single HTTP message (file contents should be a single entity). The HTTP protocol will take care of the rest but you may consider using FTP if the files you are planning to transfer are large (like `> 2GB`).

Comment: If I send a large file, will that be sent as a single HTTP request ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a multipart/form-data, then it is expected to take the entire file and send it up as a single byte stream.  Go can handle multi-gigabyte files easily this way.  But your code needs to be smart about this.

- `ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)` is out of the question unless you know for sure that the file will be very small.  Please don't do this.
- `multipartReader, err := r.MultipartReader()` use a multipart reader.  This will iterate over uploading files, in the order they are included in the encoding.  This is important, because you can keep the file entirely out of memory, and do a `Copy` from one filehandle to another.  This is how large files are handled easily.
- You will have issues with middle-boxes and reverse proxies.  We have to change defaults in Nginx so that it will not cut off large files.  Nginx (or whatever reverse-proxy you might use) will need to cooperate, as they often are going to default to some really tiny file size max like 300MB.
- Even if you think you dealt with this issue on upload with some file part trick, you will then need to deal with large files on download.  Go can do single large files very efficiently by doing a `Copy` from filehandle to filehandle.  You will also end up needing to support partial content (http 206) and not modified (304) if you want great performance for downloading files that you uploaded.  Some browsers will ignore your pleas to not ask for partial content when things like large video is involved.  So, if you don't support this, then some content will fail to download.

If you want to use some tricks to cut up files and send them in parts, then you will end up needing to use a particular Javascript library.  This is going to be quite harmful to interoperability if you are going for programmatic access from any client to your Go server.  But maybe you can't fix middle-boxes that impose size limits, and you really want to cut files up into chunks.  You will have a lot of work to handle downloading the files that you managed to upload in chunks.

Answer (score -2):

What you are trying to do is the typical code that is written with a tcp connection with most other languages, in GO you can use tcp too with net.Listen and eventually accept on the listener object. Then this should be fine.