# Flask passing uploaded file to another service using requests

Tags: python-2.7, flask, python-requests

I have Python flask webservice that takes in a file:

Headers:

Content-type: multipart/formdata

Content:

"fileTest": UPLOADED FILE

When I pass the file to another service using requests lib, I get issue where the uploaded file is not passed.

My Code:

```
files = {}
for form_file_param in request.files:
    fs = request.files[form_file_param]  # type: FileStorage
    files[form_file_param] = (fs.filename, fs.read())

req_headers = {
    "content-type": u "multipart/form-data; boundary=X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY",
}

r = requests.request(method='POST',
                     url=url,
                     headers=req_headers,
                     files=files)
```

I contact my other service directly through postman and it works successfully. I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow requests document.

> http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

```
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
files = {'file': ('report.xls', open('report.xls', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
r.text
```

Change . after watching OP response , the issue caused by header - `Content-Type`.

*This is a special content type which can be visualized as multiple sub-requests in one big request. Each of those sub-requests (one form-data element) has their own set of headers. The content type of the actual data is in there.*[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962592/whats-content-type-value-within-a-http-request-when-uploading-content)

Note : there are no different between `fs` and `fs.read()`

```
#models.py line 149
if isinstance(fp, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
    fdata = fp
else:
    data = fp.read()
```

Comment: So I found the issue. `fs` is a filestorage object and not a file-like object which requests takes in. It has method called `fs.stream` that is a file-like object. I used that and I found that `boundary=X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY` in header was also causing the issue, so i removed it and it worked. Thanks none the less.

Comment: `param files: (optional) Dictionary of ``'filename': file-like-objects`` for multipart encoding upload.`  requests.request.__doc__ .  also you can see how Content-Type create on models.py line 154   @NahinB