# Nessus File upload REST API

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, nessus

I'm trying to upload an exported scan (.nessus) file to a Nessus Community Edition server using python and the Nessus REST API (func POST /file/upload) however I keep getting the response `null` like this `{"fileuploaded":null}` in the response.

I can't seem to see in the API doc's what else could be required.

```
def upload_scan_file(_path):
    _url = url+"/file/upload"
    _head['Content-type'] = ''
    _files = {"file": open(_path, 'rb'), "no_enc" : "0"}
    r = requests.post(_url, headers=_head, verify=False, files=_files)
    return r.text
```

The reason I unset the `Content-type` key in the headers dict is that I get a `{'error': Content-type: application/json not supported'}`

`_path` contains the file path.

`_head` is a dict of header values that I use to query all the others information.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are uploading file through `files=_files` , so you should not specify `Content-type`. `Content-type` ought to be set by requests library. Read:  [Whats Content-Type value within a HTTP-Request when uploading content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962592/whats-content-type-value-within-a-http-request-when-uploading-content). Try to remove `_head['Content-type'] = ''` and change `_files` to `_files = {"file": open(_path, 'rb')}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made the `_files` change and stripped the header. When using `files=_files` in the request I get `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))` but when I use the `data=_files` request then I get a `null` with HTTP 200 again

Comment: When i saw https://docs.tenable.com/sccv/api/File.html. I think whether i lack of `Content-Type` which inside dataBoundary (`{"file": ("this is file", open(_path, 'rb'), "text/plain" )}`). And we need to add `Origin`?